# Invalid flag error when compiling a correct program in server

Tags: java

I have a basic servlet which runs perfectly in my localhost, but when the file is compiled in server, it throws a error

```
C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\analytics_1\java_files>javac -verbose -cp @"C:/Tomcat 7.0/
lib/servlet-api.jar" @"C:/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/analytics_1/java_files/json-simple-
1.1.1.jar" LogButton.java

javac: invalid flag: ½╗gIAIæUδ
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

This file runs perfectly in localhost, so i checked for jdk,jre versions, if it's added in path and class path, and everything seems to be just fine, Can't seem to figure out why there's some random string that appears for an error.

```
C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\analytics_1\java_files>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_91

C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\analytics_1\java_files>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\analytics_1\java_files>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Tomcat 7.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91;C:\Pro
gram Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre;

C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\analytics_1\java_files>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sy
stem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\scripts;C:\Program Fi
les\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramDa
ta\ComposerSetup\bin; C:\instantclient_12_1;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Java\jd
k1.8.0_91\bin;

C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\analytics_1\java_files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **@** (At the rate of symbol) from javac command and use **;** (Semicolon *used in Windows*) between multiple ClassPath separation ..

Example:
C:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\analytics_1\java_files>javac -verbose -cp "C:/Tomcat 7.0/lib/servlet-api.jar;C:/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/analytics_1/java_files/json-simple-1.1.1.jar" LogButton.java

Comment: Thank you, I never have used @ before, but at the same time,never enclosed the paths in double quotes, since the folder path contains white space, I thought @ was like some kind of escape sequence